# D3 Angular - error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a stackBlitz here - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-divided-bar?embed=1&file=src/app/bar-chart.ts&hideNavigation=1

I have a d3 chart here in Angular.

Everything works here but in my actual app I'm getting the error

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
```

which relates to this code.

```
this.y.domain(
  d3.extent(
    d3.extent(data, (d) => {
      return d.start;    
    })
    .concat(d3.extent(data, (d) => {
      return d.finish;    
    })        
  )
));
```

My actual app uses Typescript 2.7.2

Is this it do with the way I'm importing D3

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

If I remove the d3 import the error stops but I don't know how else to import d3

The full error is

```
    ERROR in .component.ts(108,7): error TS2349: C
annot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. 
Type '{ (...items: ConcatArray<string>[]): string[]; 
(...items: (string | ConcatArray<string>)[]): stri...' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Comment: i do not see any errors in the stackblitz link , can you check ?

Comment: This is my reason for the question. The Stackblitz shows no error and works but my actual app (I can't show a link) has the error. I know this question is vague but I was hoping someone might have seen this error before and offer some advise

Comment: can you please update the full error in your post ?

Comment: Check your tsconfig.json, in your local project, do you have the compiler options `esModuleInterop` and/or `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` set to true? In that case, change the import to `import d3 from 'd3';`.

Comment: @pascalpuetz I have tried this but I'm still getting the same error